# Dvd Drive Stepper Motor

Tags: motor, stepper-motor

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to make a CNC machine out of 2 dvd drive stepper motors. One of my stepper motors is completely normal and as seen in every video I've seen on the topic. The other looks like *this* (see pictures). The laser diode assembly moves on some gears connected to a motor which is connected to a board. the board has 4 contacts but according to my multimeter, only one pair is connected. Is this a stepper motor? Also, how do I get this to work with my build?

Answer (score 2):

The pictured motor is a DC motor, quite common in DVD drives. Components on PCB, located under the white (not-tooth wheel) are for measuring speed/spin direction for feedback control.

To make it work you have to see how to control a DC motor. Driving DC motor is quite easy. Try not to break the feedback control, you may find it helpful later.